# IE + Chrome - position: fixed child's content is hidden in position: fixed parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

After saving the form successfully, the message is displayed in the fixed div on the right of the screen, the message is dynamically got from server-side, when the content is short, this case is not the problem, but when it's long as in my case, I can't scroll down to see the last content of the fixed div.

HTML:

```
<div id="assistant-container">
   <div class="message">
     <div class="assistant show">
      <table><tbody>
        <tr><td><span id="icon" class="icon-check"></span>
        </td><td>
          <span class="texte">Fiche enregistrée<br>
        <br>Il faudrait au moins une méthode d'intégration pour : <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - 
        <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - 
        <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - 
        <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - 
        <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> -
        <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br> - <br>
        - <br> - <br> - <br><br>Il faudrait sélectionner au moins une règle d'intégration directe pour : 
        <br>BKCHF - Commissions et frais bancaires<br><br></span></td></tr></tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#assistant-container {
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-family: Verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 199;
    width: 50%;
    top: 10%;
    max-height: 87%;
    height: 100vh;
    right: 0px;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.message {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 210px;
    max-width: 500px;
    background-color:gray;
}

.assistant.show {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.assistant {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
    min-width: 170px;
    max-width: 350px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #868687;
    font-size: 12px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 3px rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.15);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 20px;
    transform: translateX(20%);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

jsbin : https://jsbin.com/yexiqevole/1/edit

Note: The structure of HTML can't be changed since it's not my personal project, only the CSS is fine to modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update the width of `#assistant-container` to `width: 100%;` will resolve your issue.

```
#assistant-container {
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-family: Verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 199;
    width: 100%;
    top: 10%;
    max-height: 87%;
    height: 100vh;
    right: 0px;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    background-color: green;
}


.assistant {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
    min-width: 170px;
    max-width: 350px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #868687;
    font-size: 12px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 3px rgba(160,160,160,0.15);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 20px;
    transform: translateX(20%);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    word-break: break-word;
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: It seems still the same for my side : https://jsbin.com/yahixizula/1/edit   (tested in IE)

Comment: i can see it in jsbin which you provided, there are 2 scroll.

Comment: I'm on IE 11, what about you?

Comment: It's scrollable now but do we have a way to hide that scroll bar of the child element?

Comment: yes it has to be only one scroll. If this helpful then do accept and upvote thanks :).

Comment: Sorry I was afk, and yeah, it did. I accepted the answer. Thank you ;)